# how to set frustum inortographic camera THREEJS

Tags: camera, frustum

First to thank for the great support you allways have provided me.

I have modified the SelectionBox and SelectionHelper modules published in threejs in order to work with instances.

The point is that if I try to use it with an orthographic camera the selection is not accurate. It works properly with a perspective camera.

Note:
In order to enable|disable area picking just double click left mouse button.
In order to test the code with an orthographic camera just comment perspective camera initialization and uncomment orthographic camera initialization in init function.

Here my fiddle:

`enter code here`https://jsfiddle.net/6f3gx8hb/

In perspective camera it works fine but not in ortographic camera

Best regards